# Change identical page for every site in multisite

Tags: multisite

I have an identical page on all my sites in a multisite install. I need to add a bit of text to the bottom of only that page. Is there a quick(ish) way of doing this other than going through each site in the install?

The text is identical and in most cases the link is the same, though when I say *same* I mean I'm using postname in permanent links, the IDs probably differ I would think.

I would really rather not go through each site as there are a lot of sites in the install!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this plugin, and it's worked very well for me http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpms-global-content/

When you say you're using the same postname, I'm not sure if you mean that it's dynamic or static.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I do not wish to put it on every page rather just one page per site. The page also exists.